# Create relation / link one to one between 2 entities using spring data rest

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-rest, hateoas

Following this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships I'm trying to reproduce the link creation onetoone between 2 entities with a rest put call.

However I've got the following error message when I try to link addresses/1 & libraries/1/libraryAddress
curl -i -X PUT -d "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
  -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/libraries/1/libraryAddress

**"Must send only 1 link to update a property reference that isn't a List or a Map"**

Detail :

```
// Data model
// Master library class which have one address
@Entity
public class Library {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @RestResource(path = "libraryAddress", rel="address")
    private Address address;

    // standard constructor, getters, setters
}

// Address linked with a onetoone relation with library
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String location;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Library library;

    // standard constructor, getters, setters
}

// Repositories
public interface LibraryRepository extends CrudRepository<Library, Long> {}
public interface AddressRepository extends CrudRepository<Address, Long> {}
```

queries made with the rest api :

*create a library*

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"name":"My Library"}' http://localhost:8080/libraries
```

*create an adress*

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"location":"Main Street nr 5"}' http://localhost:8080/addresses
```

*create the association*

```
curl -i -X PUT -d "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
  -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/libraries/1/libraryAddress
```

--> Error {"cause":null,"message":"Must send only 1 link to update a property reference that isn't a List or a Map."}

Have you got any clues to resolve this problem ?

Regards,
Blured.

Comment: I'm using spring-boot 2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: Have you tried to download the project source-code from GitHub and running it? I just did and the request which fails for you works as described in the article.
I notice that the downloaded example project uses Spring Boot 2.1.7, for what it is worth.

Comment: I'm gonna give a try ! there is also one specificity it's that I embed the spring-boot-starter-hateoas library for other tests. Perhaps there is a conflict.

Comment: With Spring Boot 2.1.7 is working, I just test it.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a bug in Spring Boot 2.2.0 `org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController` class at line 321:

```
if (source.getLinks().hasSingleLink()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Must send only 1 link to update a property reference that isn't a List or a Map.");
}
```

It should be:

```
if (!source.getLinks().hasSingleLink()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Must send only 1 link to update a property reference that isn't a List or a Map.");
}
```

Here is the code for String Boot 2.1.7

```
if (source.getLinks().size() != 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Must send only 1 link to update a property reference that isn't a List or a Map.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of orders are compliant with 2.1.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but not with spring-boot 2.2.0.RELEASE

Things might have changed in this version. I will look at that. However thanks for having pointing that.

Somebody has already managed to run those kind of rest calls with 2.2.0 ?